# How do .net 4.0 [named] tuples work under the hood?

Tags: .net-4.0, tuples

I suspect that there is a lot of work done at low level.

when names are used for tuple elements, do auto-properties get created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)?

Comment: Tuples are described here:http://www.davidhayden.me/2009/12/tuple-in-c-4-c-4-examples.html

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I know Python better than some newer C# features, so I am influenced by the terminology I know.

Comment: I guess I am thinking of both the Anonymous Types as well as tuples, since Python does not have that differentiation ;)

Comment: `Tuple` is a regular class.  Anonymous types generate a hidden class.